# Define f: Z /6Z by g(5[a]) = [5a]

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

So, in our notes, we had an example where we defined f: Z / 6 Z by g([a]) = [5a] (where z is set of all integers)

Already, I don't follow what the g([a]) = [5a] means, I'm assuming they are equivalence classes?

then he wrote :

[0]-> [0]
[1] -> [5]
[2] -> [4]
[3] -> [3]
[4] -> [2]
[5] -> [1]

NOT SURE what this means either.

Finally he wrote gcd(5,6) = 1
5s + 6t= 1

not sure why this is relevant or how he used it?

Please help. He went on to prove this, but I just want to understand what is going on, or what I'm supposed to try and prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, equivalence classes, of the equivalence relation $a\equiv b \pmod6$ which is defined as
$$ 6\ \ |\ \ a-b\,.$$ 
In other words, in the quotient $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ we regard two numbers *equal* if they differ by $6k$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. In symbols it is just
$$[a]=[b] \ \iff\ a\equiv b\pmod6\,.$$
Now observe that
$$g([2])=[5\cdot 2]=[10]=[4]$$
because $10-4$ is divisible by $6$.

You can also observe that $[5]=[-1]$ which makes the calculations even easier..

The fact that $5$ is **coprime** to $6$, that is, $\gcd(6,5)=1$, can be just a side note at this stage. Its importance in general is that the function $x\mapsto a\cdot x$ in $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is *bijective* (one-to-one correspondence) iff $a$ is coprime to $m$. 
 In other words, one can thus *divide* by $a$ modulo $m$.